# How to add another reportviewercontrolhandler with different version on web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-config

I was planning on adding another handler in my webconfig to make my reportviewer and updatepanel works

this is my current web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>

    <!-- another handler to add here  -->

      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>

    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

i tried adding this handler

```
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandlerV15" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
```

and it works then after the next day for some reason the other system will not work, then i tried changing the name of the handler then it works again, then after that it will not work again, its been looping for days, i was wondering if i have to add something more to resolve this issue.

there was other system that was set up as for version 11 only, but my work is for version 15 so i was researching stuff for web config but sadly i didnt get any solution

Comment: Can I see the place where you're using this handler, in your code? "ReportViewerWebControlHandler"

Comment: actually im not really familiar with this, but when i make my program ive been using the reportviewer version 15, but i didnt know that i have to make it version 11, but when i change the web config into version 11, the updatepanels and reportviewers is not working, so i was thinking of having 2 handlers so i can make it both v15 and v11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a conflict with the handler configurations in your `web.config` file when trying to use both `version 11` and `version 15`.

If possible, you can route requests for different versions of `ReportViewer` to different paths. For example:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandlerV11" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="ReportViewer11/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
        <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandlerV15" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="ReportViewer15/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This way, you have distinct paths for version 11 and version 15, and there won't be any conflicts.

Comment: thank you for the reply sir, but where could i found the path of reportviewers? im kinda new in this config so i dont really know much stuff on this

Comment: The path to the handler should be specified in the configuration or code where you initialize the ReportViewer control. It may look something like this: `ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/YourReportPath/YourReportName";`